# knockout change css class on presence of a key in observable array

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I have a case here

http://jsfiddle.net/jX6m2/6/

I have an observable array, and i have a single component, which is to vouch for the presence of a value in the given observable array and change the css if it exists so.

for ex in this script i am to check, if the word "hello" exists in the array and if it does than change the css to blue

SCRIPT

```
function VM() {
    var arrInterests = 'hello,world'.split(',');    
    this.interests = ko.observableArray(arrInterests);
};

ko.applyBindings((new VM()));
```

HTML

```
<p class="green" data-bind="css: { 'blue': interests() === 'hello'}">Hello exists:
</p>
```

CSS

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
    border:2px solid red;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to search for a value within arrays:

```
interests().indexOf('hello') >= 0
```

Of course, you should put this code in a computed property inside of the viewmodel:

```
function VM() {
    var arrInterests = 'hello,world'.split(',');    
    this.interests = ko.observableArray(arrInterests);
    this.contains = function(value) {
        return ko.computed(function() {
            return this.interests().indexOf(value) >= 0;
        });
    };
};

// usage

<p class="green" data-bind="css: { 'blue': contains('hello') }">Hello exists:</p>
<p class="green" data-bind="css: { 'red': contains('world') }">world exists:</p>
....
```